# On the convergence of an Euclidean path integral in 0+0D

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, integration, mathematics

Suppose we have an integral $$Z(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} dx e^{-\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{\lambda}{4!}x^4}.$$ To my knowledge this is a possible integral which can arise in QFT. My question is on the convergence of this integral. For what $\lambda$ will this integral be convergent? I'm not looking for an explicit solution, just something to get me on my way. It seems like just trying values is a bit arbitrary and I believe there must be a better way.

I've seen some posts referencing this integral (e.g. [The Partition Function of $0$-Dimensional $\phi^{4}$ Theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/710140/)) but these didn't really answer my question.

Comment: This might be interesting to you: https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.2714

Comment: With respect to the standard definition of convergent integrals in measure theory books like Folland etc. this integral converges if and only if ${\rm Re}(\lambda)\ge 0$. However, the function $Z(\lambda)$ analytically continues to the entire complex plane minus a cut on the negative real axis, as can be seen with the change of variable $x=\lambda^{-\frac{1}{4}} y$.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam How do you show the complex side of your answer?

Comment: You do the change of variable, then you expand the gaussian/quadratic part as a perturbation of the quartic part. This expansion converges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $\Re[\lambda]\geq 0$ we have $$\left|e^{-\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{\lambda}{4!}x^4}\right|\leq e^{-\frac{x^2}{2!}},$$ that is the integral is less than the Gaussian integral, which is convergent.

For $\Re[\lambda] <0$ the exponent grows as $x\rightarrow \pm\infty$, since $x^4$ eventually grows faster than $x^2$, so the integral diverges.

Comment: This I should have seen. I'd prefer to have gotten a hint before the solution, but thanks for the answer anyway! I'm accepting this one as the solution since it is worked out more.

Comment: What happens if $\lambda$ is imaginary? Will it hold either way?

Comment: @Geigercounter inequalities are defined for real numbers, as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

The absolute value of the integrand is $e^{-\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{{\rm Re}\lambda}{4!}x^4}$.
The integrand is integrable and the integral is convergent if ${\rm Re}\lambda\geq 0$.